# Keystore file does not exist using iCloud Drive in Android Studio terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, icloud

I have a keystore file in my Documents folder on my Mac which I recently switched iCloud on

When I run the command `keytool -list -v /Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Android/mykeystore.ks` I get the error

> Keystore file does not exist

I can cd to the directory so I know I can drill down to my Documents/Android folder and I can also see the file in my iCloud on iCloud.com

Why can Android not find the file?

Comment: Looking at my own list of directories on my Mac, it seems that the iCloud Drive directory only exists in your user directory (`~/Library/Mobile\ Documents`), not the root directory (`/Library/Mobile\ Documents`).

Comment: Thanks @Edric - tried that but still no luck